Incompatibility between times and tcolorbox with breakable
There seems to be an incompatibility between packages times and tcolorbox (with the option breakable). I did extensive search on the Internet but wasn't able to find anything. I was not able to produce a MWE, however. Does anybody know something about this issue and a possible solution?
Thanks in advance,
Marcus.
P.S.
The following MWE shows the problem (sorry that I couldn't make it shorter). The box in page 3 is unbroken, and this causes lots os spaces to be inserted in page 2.
\documentclass [chapterprefix=true,pagesize=false,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,fontsize=10pt,twoside,open=right,cleardoublepage=empty,headsepline=off]{scrbook}
\usepackage[driver=none]{geometry}
\geometry{
    mag=1000,
    paperheight=24.0cm, paperwidth=17.0cm,
    height=20.8cm, width=13.2cm,
    textheight=19.8cm, textwidth=13.2cm,
    headheight=0.5cm, headsep=0.5cm,
    includehead,
    twoside,
    inner=2.0cm, outer=2.0cm, top=1.0cm, bottom=1.7cm,
    nomarginpar
    }
\usepackage[a4,center,cam,dvips,noinfo]{crop}
\crop
\usepackage [table]{xcolor}
\usepackage [brazilian] {babel}
\usepackage [utf8] {inputenc}
\usepackage [T1] {fontenc}
\usepackage {url}
\usepackage {times}
\usepackage {float}
\usepackage {syntax}
\usepackage {colortbl}
\usepackage [numbers,square] {natbib} 
\usepackage {caption}
\usepackage {makeidx}
\usepackage {multirow}
\usepackage {tabularx}
\usepackage {fancybox}
\usepackage {multicol}
\usepackage {amsfonts}          
\usepackage {amsmath}
\usepackage {amssymb}
\usepackage {latexsym}
\usepackage {ragged2e}
\usepackage {longtable}
\usepackage [breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage {microtype}
\usepackage {bibentry}
\usepackage {graphicx}
\usepackage [anythingbreaks]{breakurl}
\usepackage {listings}
\usepackage {enumitem}
\usepackage {bussproofs}
\usepackage {ntheorem}

\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}

\allowdisplaybreaks
\newcommand {\zbar} {\,|\,}
\newcommand {\lt} {$\lambda$-termo}
\newcommand {\lts} {$\lambda$-termos}
\newcommand{\destaque}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\foreign}[1]{\emph{#1}}  
\newcommand {\lbl} [1]{\LeftLabel{\scriptsize{$(#1)$}}}
\newcommand{\capituloEditora}[1]{\chapter{#1}}
\newcommand{\capituloEditoraEstrela}[1]{\chapter*{#1}}
\newcommand{\secaoEditora}[1]{\section{#1}} 
\newcommand{\subsecaoEditora}[1]{\subsection{#1}}
\newcommand{\citar}[1]{\cite{#1}}
\newcommand{\indice}[1]{\index{#1|textbf}{}}
\newcommand{\subindice}[2]{\index{#1!#2}{}}

\begin {document}
\chapter {Cálculo lambda tipado}
\label {cap-cltipado}

O Cálculo Lambda não tipado é bastante poderoso e capaz de representar qualquer computação. No entanto, ele permite a formulação de alguns paradoxos (o mais famoso é o Paradoxo de Russell, descrito a seguir) e por isso ele foi substituído por uma versão menos poderosa (mas felizmente ainda poderosa o suficiente para ser usada na computação) porém isenta de paradoxos. Esta substituição ocorreu a partir da incorporação da noção de ``tipo'' no Cálculo Lambda, que assim passou a ter todos os seus termos ``tipados`'' e por isso recebeu o nome de Cálculo Lambda Tipado.

O Cálculo Lambda Tipado, estudado no presente capítulo é, portanto, uma extensão do Cálculo Lambda não tipado estudado no Capítulo \ref {cap-clnaotipado} e goza da maioria das propriedades deste último, sendo por outro lado um pouco mais restrito. 

Além de ser usado na representação de computações (entre outras coisas), o Cálculo Lambda Tipado deu origem à chamada Teoria de Tipos e foi a inspiração para a incorporação da noção de ``tipos'' na maioria das linguagens de programação em uso ao longo da história e atualmente.

O conteúdo deste capítulo é baseado em \citar {nederpelt2014}, \citar {hindley2008}, \citar {wiki-tlc} e \citar {wiki-stlc}. Os problemas da Seção \ref {sec-exemplos} são de \citar {nederpelt2014}, as soluções são do autor.

\secaoEditora {Introdução}

As principais vantagens e desvantagens do Cálculo Lambda Não Tipado (Capítulo \ref {cap-clnaotipado}) podem ser resumidas da seguinte forma:
\begin {itemize}
\item \subindice {cálculo lambda não tipado}{aspectos positivos} Aspectos positivos:
      \begin {itemize}
      \item Simples, conciso e elegante.
      \item Confluência e unicidade de formas normais $\beta$.
      \item Resolução de equações recursivas por meio de pontos fixos.
      \item Turing-completo.
      \end {itemize}
\item \subindice {cálculo lambda não tipado}{aspectos negativos} Aspectos negativos:
      \begin {itemize}
      \item Excessivamente liberal (contra-intuitivo em alguns aspectos).
      \item Auto-aplicação é permitida ($x x$) porém é contra-intuitiva.
      \item A existência de formas normais não é garantida, existe a possibilidade de cálculos infinitos.
      \item Todo termo possui um ponto fixo, o que não corresponde ao que se conhece do comportamento usual das funções (algumas possuem, outras não).
      \end {itemize}
\end {itemize}

\secaoEditora {Tipos dependentes de tipos ($\lambda \underline {w}$)}
\label {sec-lambdaw}

\subindice {cálculo lambda tipado}{$\lambda \underline {w}$}\subindice {cálculo lambda tipado}{tipos dependentes de tipos|see {$\lambda  \underline {w}$}}O STLC estendido com tipos dependentes de tipos é denotado $\lambda \underline {w}$. Quando um tipo pode ser expresso em função de outro tipo, isto possibilita a definição de tipos polimórficos, ou seja, tipos que são parametrizados em função de outros tipos. Isto costuma ser muito útil quando as características e propriedades do tipo base permanecem inalteradas quando este é instanciado com um ou outro tipo.

Uma \subindice {tipo}{polimórfico}\destaque {tipo polimórfico} é um tipo que abstrai um tipo (ou seja, uma função que retorna um tipo e que possui um tipo como parâmetro). Este recurso, presente em muitas linguagens de programação, permite a construção de tipos genéricos nas quais o tipo específico do argumento sendo manipulado é um parâmetro da função, neste caso representado por uma \subindice {variável}{de tipo}\destaque {variável de tipo} (\foreign {typing variable}, uma variável cujo valor é um tipo válido no sistema). 

\subsecaoEditora {Regras de derivação}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,title=Regras de derivação para $\lambda \underline {w}$]
\begin {prooftree}
\lbl{sort}
\AxiomC{$\emptyset\vdash *:\square$}
\end {prooftree}

\begin {prooftree}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash A:*$}
\lbl{var*}
\UnaryInfC{$\Gamma, x:A\vdash x:A$}
\end {prooftree}

\begin {prooftree}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash A:\square$}
\lbl{var\square}
\UnaryInfC{$\Gamma, x:A\vdash x:A$}
\end {prooftree}

\begin {prooftree}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash A:B$}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash C:*$}
\lbl{weak*}
\BinaryInfC{$\Gamma, x:C\vdash A:B$}
\end {prooftree}

\begin {prooftree}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash A:B$}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash C:\square$}
\lbl{weak\square}
\BinaryInfC{$\Gamma, x:C\vdash A:B$}
\end {prooftree}

\begin {prooftree}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash A:*$}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash B:*$}
\lbl{form*}
\BinaryInfC{$\Gamma\vdash A\rightarrow B:*$}
\end {prooftree}

\begin {prooftree}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash A:\square$}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash B:\square$}
\lbl{form*}
\BinaryInfC{$\Gamma\vdash A\rightarrow B:\square$}
\end {prooftree}

\begin {prooftree}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash M:A\rightarrow B$}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash N:A$}
\lbl{appl}
\BinaryInfC{$\Gamma\vdash MN:B$}
\end {prooftree}

\begin {prooftree}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma, x:A\vdash M:B$}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash A\rightarrow B:*$}
\lbl{abst*}
\BinaryInfC{$\Gamma\vdash \lambda x:A.M:A\rightarrow B$}
\end {prooftree}

\begin {prooftree}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma, x:A\vdash M:B$}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash A\rightarrow B:\square$}
\lbl{abst\square}
\BinaryInfC{$\Gamma\vdash \lambda x:A.M:A\rightarrow B$}
\end {prooftree}

\begin {prooftree}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash A:B$}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash B':*$}
\lbl{conv*}
\BinaryInfC{$\Gamma\vdash A:B'$}
\end {prooftree}

\begin {prooftree}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash A:B$}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash B':\square$}
\lbl{conv\square}
\BinaryInfC{$\Gamma\vdash A:B'$}
\end {prooftree}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end {document}


If I use both packages (times and tcolorbox), breakable does not work and fonts are ok. If I remove times (and keep tcolorbox), breakable works and fonts look ugly.

the times package is just three lines long and completely unrelated to anything tcolorbox does. If you have an example with an error show the example then someone may be able to help

You can always make a MWE, just start with a copy of the document with an error and delete everything you can delete while still showing the error

The times package has been obsolete for a quarter of a century.

I have inserted a MWE that shows the problem in the original post. Sorry if it is not quite minimal.

You can easily make that example shorter by removing the packages not required to reproduce the problem. Or are you really claiming the error can be resolved by removing any of them?

This has nothing to do with times, which, by the way, is an obsolete package.
Indeed, if you remove the package, the problem remains the same: a very big object that makes finding suitable page breaks impossible. Here's a picture of what I get when I comment out \usepackage{times}:

In my opinion, such a big object should be a float, instead of a breakable box, but that's your decision.
The main problem is that \section sets a conditional that makes LaTeX into avoiding untimely page breaks and this clashes with the breaking abilities of tcolorbox. You can simply add the key ignore break (but beware of a possible bad page break).
Thanks to Ulrike Fischer for suggesting the ignore nobreak key.
I modified your preamble, check the comments. Do you really need the syntax package? It's very old, unmaintained and a bit dangerous.
Instead of times I used newtx. In order to better show that the tcolorbox breaks, I repeated some text.
\documentclass[
  chapterprefix=true,
  pagesize=false,
  listof=totoc,
  bibliography=totoc,
  fontsize=10pt,
  twoside,
  open=right,
  cleardoublepage=empty,
  headsepline=off
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[driver=none]{geometry}

\geometry{
    mag=1000,
    paperheight=24.0cm, paperwidth=17.0cm,
    height=20.8cm, width=13.2cm,
    textheight=19.8cm, textwidth=13.2cm,
    headheight=0.5cm, headsep=0.5cm,
    includehead,
    twoside,
    inner=2.0cm, outer=2.0cm, top=1.0cm, bottom=1.7cm,
    nomarginpar
    }
\usepackage[a4,center,cam,dvips,noinfo]{crop}
\crop

\usepackage{newtx}

\usepackage [table]{xcolor}
\usepackage [brazilian] {babel}
%\usepackage [utf8] {inputenc}% no longer needed
\usepackage [T1] {fontenc}
\usepackage {url}
%\usepackage {times}% obsolete
\usepackage {float}
%\usepackage {syntax}% dangerous
%\usepackage {colortbl}% already loaded by xcolor
\usepackage [numbers,square] {natbib} 
\usepackage {caption}
\usepackage {makeidx}
\usepackage {multirow}
\usepackage {tabularx}
\usepackage {fancybox}
\usepackage {multicol}
\usepackage {amsfonts}          
\usepackage {amsmath}
%\usepackage {amssymb}% not with newtx
%\usepackage {latexsym}% obsolete
\usepackage {ragged2e}
\usepackage {longtable}
\usepackage {microtype}
\usepackage {bibentry}
\usepackage {graphicx}
\usepackage [anythingbreaks]{breakurl}
\usepackage {listings}
\usepackage {enumitem}
\usepackage {bussproofs}
\usepackage {ntheorem}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage [breaklinks]{hyperref}% should go last


\allowdisplaybreaks
\newcommand {\zbar} {\,|\,}
\newcommand {\lt} {$\lambda$-termo}
\newcommand {\lts} {$\lambda$-termos}
\newcommand{\destaque}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\foreign}[1]{\emph{#1}}  
\newcommand {\lbl} [1]{\LeftLabel{{\scriptsize $(#1)$}}}% <--- changed
\newcommand{\capituloEditora}[1]{\chapter{#1}}
\newcommand{\capituloEditoraEstrela}[1]{\chapter*{#1}}
\newcommand{\secaoEditora}[1]{\section{#1}} 
\newcommand{\subsecaoEditora}[1]{\subsection{#1}}
\newcommand{\citar}[1]{\cite{#1}}
\newcommand{\indice}[1]{\index{#1|textbf}{}}
\newcommand{\subindice}[2]{\index{#1!#2}{}}

\begin {document}
\chapter {Cálculo lambda tipado}
\label {cap-cltipado}

O Cálculo Lambda não tipado é bastante poderoso e capaz de representar qualquer computação. No entanto, ele permite a formulação de alguns paradoxos (o mais famoso é o Paradoxo de Russell, descrito a seguir) e por isso ele foi substituído por uma versão menos poderosa (mas felizmente ainda poderosa o suficiente para ser usada na computação) porém isenta de paradoxos. Esta substituição ocorreu a partir da incorporação da noção de ``tipo'' no Cálculo Lambda, que assim passou a ter todos os seus termos ``tipados`'' e por isso recebeu o nome de Cálculo Lambda Tipado.

O Cálculo Lambda Tipado, estudado no presente capítulo é, portanto, uma extensão do Cálculo Lambda não tipado estudado no Capítulo \ref {cap-clnaotipado} e goza da maioria das propriedades deste último, sendo por outro lado um pouco mais restrito. 

Além de ser usado na representação de computações (entre outras coisas), o Cálculo Lambda Tipado deu origem à chamada Teoria de Tipos e foi a inspiração para a incorporação da noção de ``tipos'' na maioria das linguagens de programação em uso ao longo da história e atualmente.

O conteúdo deste capítulo é baseado em \citar {nederpelt2014}, \citar {hindley2008}, \citar {wiki-tlc} e \citar {wiki-stlc}. Os problemas da Seção \ref {sec-exemplos} são de \citar {nederpelt2014}, as soluções são do autor.

\secaoEditora {Introdução}

As principais vantagens e desvantagens do Cálculo Lambda Não Tipado (Capítulo \ref {cap-clnaotipado}) podem ser resumidas da seguinte forma:
\begin {itemize}
\item \subindice {cálculo lambda não tipado}{aspectos positivos} Aspectos positivos:
      \begin {itemize}
      \item Simples, conciso e elegante.
      \item Confluência e unicidade de formas normais $\beta$.
      \item Resolução de equações recursivas por meio de pontos fixos.
      \item Turing-completo.
      \end {itemize}
\item \subindice {cálculo lambda não tipado}{aspectos negativos} Aspectos negativos:
      \begin {itemize}
      \item Excessivamente liberal (contra-intuitivo em alguns aspectos).
      \item Auto-aplicação é permitida ($x x$) porém é contra-intuitiva.
      \item A existência de formas normais não é garantida, existe a possibilidade de cálculos infinitos.
      \item Todo termo possui um ponto fixo, o que não corresponde ao que se conhece do comportamento usual das funções (algumas possuem, outras não).
      \end {itemize}
\end {itemize}

\secaoEditora {Tipos dependentes de tipos ($\lambda \underline {w}$)}
\label {sec-lambdaw}

\subindice {cálculo lambda tipado}{$\lambda \underline {w}$}\subindice {cálculo lambda tipado}{tipos dependentes de tipos|see {$\lambda  \underline {w}$}}O STLC estendido com tipos dependentes de tipos é denotado $\lambda \underline {w}$. Quando um tipo pode ser expresso em função de outro tipo, isto possibilita a definição de tipos polimórficos, ou seja, tipos que são parametrizados em função de outros tipos. Isto costuma ser muito útil quando as características e propriedades do tipo base permanecem inalteradas quando este é instanciado com um ou outro tipo.

Uma \subindice {tipo}{polimórfico}\destaque {tipo polimórfico} é um tipo que abstrai um tipo (ou seja, uma função que retorna um tipo e que possui um tipo como parâmetro). Este recurso, presente em muitas linguagens de programação, permite a construção de tipos genéricos nas quais o tipo específico do argumento sendo manipulado é um parâmetro da função, neste caso representado por uma \subindice {variável}{de tipo}\destaque {variável de tipo} (\foreign {typing variable}, uma variável cujo valor é um tipo válido no sistema). 

%%%% text added to show that the box breaks
Uma \subindice {tipo}{polimórfico}\destaque {tipo polimórfico} é um tipo que abstrai um tipo (ou seja, uma função que retorna um tipo e que possui um tipo como parâmetro). Este recurso, presente em muitas linguagens de programação, permite a construção de tipos genéricos nas quais o tipo específico do argumento sendo manipulado é um parâmetro da função, neste caso representado por uma \subindice {variável}{de tipo}\destaque {variável de tipo} (\foreign {typing variable}, uma variável cujo valor é um tipo válido no sistema). 
Uma \subindice {tipo}{polimórfico}\destaque {tipo polimórfico} é um tipo que abstrai um tipo (ou seja, uma função que retorna um tipo e que possui um tipo como parâmetro). Este recurso, presente em muitas linguagens de programação, permite a construção de tipos genéricos nas quais o tipo específico do argumento sendo manipulado é um parâmetro da função, neste caso representado por uma \subindice {variável}{de tipo}\destaque {variável de tipo} (\foreign {typing variable}, uma variável cujo valor é um tipo válido no sistema). 
Uma \subindice {tipo}{polimórfico}\destaque {tipo polimórfico} é um tipo que abstrai um tipo (ou seja, uma função que retorna um tipo e que possui um tipo como parâmetro). Este recurso, presente em muitas linguagens de programação, permite a construção de tipos genéricos nas quais o tipo específico do argumento sendo manipulado é um parâmetro da função, neste caso representado por uma \subindice {variável}{de tipo}\destaque {variável de tipo} (\foreign {typing variable}, uma variável cujo valor é um tipo válido no sistema). 
%%%

\subsecaoEditora {Regras de derivação}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  breakable,
  ignore nobreak,
  title=Regras de derivação para $\lambda \underline {w}$
]
\begin {prooftree}
\lbl{sort}
\AxiomC{$\emptyset\vdash *:\square$}
\end {prooftree}

\begin {prooftree}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash A:*$}
\lbl{var*}
\UnaryInfC{$\Gamma, x:A\vdash x:A$}
\end {prooftree}

\begin {prooftree}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash A:\square$}
\lbl{var\square}
\UnaryInfC{$\Gamma, x:A\vdash x:A$}
\end {prooftree}

\begin {prooftree}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash A:B$}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash C:*$}
\lbl{weak*}
\BinaryInfC{$\Gamma, x:C\vdash A:B$}
\end {prooftree}

\begin {prooftree}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash A:B$}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash C:\square$}
\lbl{weak\square}
\BinaryInfC{$\Gamma, x:C\vdash A:B$}
\end {prooftree}

\begin {prooftree}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash A:*$}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash B:*$}
\lbl{form*}
\BinaryInfC{$\Gamma\vdash A\rightarrow B:*$}
\end {prooftree}

\begin {prooftree}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash A:\square$}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash B:\square$}
\lbl{form*}
\BinaryInfC{$\Gamma\vdash A\rightarrow B:\square$}
\end {prooftree}

\begin {prooftree}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash M:A\rightarrow B$}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash N:A$}
\lbl{appl}
\BinaryInfC{$\Gamma\vdash MN:B$}
\end {prooftree}

\begin {prooftree}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma, x:A\vdash M:B$}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash A\rightarrow B:*$}
\lbl{abst*}
\BinaryInfC{$\Gamma\vdash \lambda x:A.M:A\rightarrow B$}
\end {prooftree}

\begin {prooftree}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma, x:A\vdash M:B$}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash A\rightarrow B:\square$}
\lbl{abst\square}
\BinaryInfC{$\Gamma\vdash \lambda x:A.M:A\rightarrow B$}
\end {prooftree}

\begin {prooftree}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash A:B$}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash B':*$}
\lbl{conv*}
\BinaryInfC{$\Gamma\vdash A:B'$}
\end {prooftree}

\begin {prooftree}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash A:B$}
\AxiomC {$\Gamma\vdash B':\square$}
\lbl{conv\square}
\BinaryInfC{$\Gamma\vdash A:B'$}
\end {prooftree}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end {document}



tcolorbox has a key ignore nobreak.

@UlrikeFischer It has so many keys!
